# allowedaction from objectType opencmis

Tags: opencmis

I m working with  acl and i can't do this

Session.getTypeDefinition().getChildren().getAllowableActions()

any help and thx

Comment: StackOverflow only allows for english-written content.

Answer (score 1):

Type definitions don't have Allowable Actions. Only concrete objects (documents, folders, etc.) have Allowable Actions (and maybe ACLs).